# Review queue pages should put tags near top

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues

In review queue pages, particularly votes to close, the **tags** identifying the context of a post sometimes seem buried too far below the heading.

I'd like to suggest that the tags of the question should be moved near the top of the page, even when reviewing an answer. The benefit of this would be to allow a reviewer to quickly skip review items for which they lack needed context.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is necessary; for starters, the normal question page also has tags at the bottom of the question. Moving them to the top of the review page might confuse people. However, the main reason this isn't necessary is that you can already filter the review queue by tags if you are concerned about context or subject matter expertise.

Answer (score 3):

The only scenario I could see this being useful for would be when reviewing a duplicate in CV/RV. The thing about that is:

- People who are interested in those usually already filter to the tags where they know their way around the duplicates
- People who aren't interested will simply filter out duplicates.

For every other review task, you are almost never expected to know the material; in my experience, good knowledge of the rules and attention to detail will usually suffice. I've **almost never** needed knowledge of the tag material to review answers, either—ever noticed how none of the VLQ comments mention technical accuracy?